# How dynamically load from remote server and show to user while typing

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I need to build a select input with Select2 3.4.5v whit this requirement:

1. Multi select ability
2. ability to typing and select options that is not in list.
3. load data list while user typing (depend on user query) (if query is
   more than n character)
4. the final value of input be a contact of selected items with a
   delimiter character like "|",
5. migrate to newer version Select2 plugin is not possible for project

I need something like Tag suggestion example like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="e12" style="width:300px" value="brown, red, green"/>   

$("#e12").select2({tags:["red", "green", "blue"]});
```

BUT with remote data loading. i hoped to trigger load data on input changing. (or even on appended input)

`<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen1" style="width: 10px;">`

but nothing trigger (except change that is not useful for my situation).

can someone help me to figure out?

Comment: I could only get it to work on a newer version... sorry =/

Comment: can you tell me how to do this in newer version?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick (this is using the most recent version of `Select2`). It supports multi-select, as well as searching when the user is typing. In this example it searches `GitHub` repositories.

I would also recommend [checking out their documentation](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api) as it was very useful in helping me understand this.

[CodePen mirror](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/oOerQN)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-data-ajax").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function(params) {
        return {
          q: params.term,
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function(data, params) {
        params.page = params.page || 1;
        return {
          results: data.items,
          pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
          }
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
    placeholder: 'Search Github for a repository',
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    multiple: true,
    templateResult: function(repo) {
      return repo.full_name;
    },
    templateSelection: function(repo) {
      return repo.full_name || repo.text;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400|Muli:300,400|Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://select2.org/assets/7c647dd1b60ff2b17a493d7f00a18e26.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="js-example-data-ajax form-control" style="width: 300px;"></select>
```